# Array Out of bounds error VB

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Sorry for the terrible wording on my last question, I was half asleep and it was midnight. This time I'll try to be more clear.

I'm currently writing some code for a mini barcode scanner and stock manager program. I've got the input and everything sorted out, but there is a problem with my arrays.

I'm currently trying to extract the contents of the stock file and sort them out into product tables.
This is my current code for getting the data:

```
        Using fs As StreamReader = New StreamReader("The File Path (Is private)")
        Dim line As String = "ERROR"
        line = fs.ReadLine()
        While line <> Nothing

            Dim pos As Integer = 0
            Dim split(3) As String
            pos = products.Length
            split = line.Split("|")
            productCodes(productCodes.Length) = split(0)
            products(products.Length, 0) = split(1)
            products(products.Length, 1) = split(2)
            products(products.Length, 2) = split(3)
            line = fs.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using
```

I have made sure that the file path does, in fact, go to the file. I have looked through debug to find that all the data is going through into my "split" table. The error throws as soon as I start trying to transfer the data.

This is where I declare the two tables being used:

```
    Dim productCodes() As String = {}
    Dim products(,) As Object = {}
```

Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance
~Hydro

Comment: you create empty arrays so any index access will be out of bounds, give them the required size (or better use a resizable container)

Comment: Use `List(Of String)` for `Dim productCodes() As String = {}` and create a class which represents your data instead of using two-dimensional array. Then you can use `List(Of YourData)`

Comment: Because you need to provide size of array before reading file, arrays will work only in case you have same number of lines always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring the arrays like you did:

```
Dim productCodes() As String = {}
Dim products(,) As Object = {}
```

You are assigning size 0 to all your arrays, so during your loop, it will eventually try to access a position that haven't been previously declared to the compiler. It is the same as declaring an array of size 10 `Dim MyArray(10)` and try to access the position 11 `MyArray(11) = something`.

You should either declare it with a proper size, or redim it during execution time:

```
Dim productCodes(10) As String
```

or

```
Dim productCodes() As String
Dim Products(,) As String
Dim Position as integer = 0
'code here
While line <> Nothing      
    Redim Preserve productCodes(Position)
    Redim Preserve products(2,Position)
    Dim split(3) As String
    pos = products.Length
    split = line.Split("|")
    productCodes(Position) = split(0)
    products(0,Position) = split(1)
    products(1,Position) = split(2)
    products(2,Position) = split(3)
    line = fs.ReadLine()
    Position+=1
End While
```

Comment: The choice of word can be misleading (especially for future reader with begineer knowledge) : `Dim arr(10)` doesn't create an array of size 10 but of size 11 (0 to 10) and in `arr(11)` 11 isn't a position (as in "we're getting the 11th item") but an *(zero based)* index.